# Updating a field from database using ajax with codeigniter active record fails

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a problem in updating the `qty` field in my database using ajax. I don't know where the error occur because when I tried to click the minus button it keeps on subtracting it multiple times. I've google same problem but didn't find any solution. Here is my code.

Here is my **CONTROLLER:**

```
 public function deduct(){
    $this->inpatient_model->deduct();
    $data['inpatient'] = $this->inpatient_model->getinpatientlab();
    $this->load->view('admin/queryinpatient',$data);
 }
```

Here is my **MODEL:**

```
 public function deduct(){  
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('inpatientlab');
    $this->db->where('ilid',$this->input->post('lid'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->result_array();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        if($row[0]['qty'] > 1){
            $uno = 1;
            $this->db->set('qty','qty-'.$uno,FALSE)
                    ->where('ilid',$this->input->post('lid'))
                    ->update('inpatientlab');               
        }
    }   

}
```

Here is my **VIEW:**

```
<?php if($inpatient): ?>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>            
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Sub Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($inpatient as $rows): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows->ldesc; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->qty; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->lprice; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo number_format($rows->qty * $rows->lprice,2); ?></td>
        <td>
            <button value="<?php echo $rows->ilid; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
            <button value="<?php echo $rows->ilid; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btnMinus"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    (function(){        
    $(document).on('click','.btnMinus',function(){
        var lid = $(this).val(),
            pid = $('.pid').val(),
            dataString = "id=" + pid + "&lid=" + lid;           
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: base_url + "inpatient/deduct",
                data:dataString,
                success:function(data){
                    $('.pickedlab').html(data);
                }
            })
        return false;

    });

})()
```

My `View` in here is also loaded via ajax inside a bootstrap-modal. I really have no idea why it keeps on subtracting multiple times. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the browser debug and find out whether your AJAX is calling multiple times.  I am not familiar with your Controller-Model settings, normally my models are pure POCO class only.  All computations are done at the controller level.

Comment: Yes I tried checking up my console and it keeps on sending multiple times. I don't know where to put it right. And whats POCO by the way?